# custom variable issue in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Hi am using the following code to track the clicks of the users using custom variable. But in my custom variables report the count is getting increased for user log in but not for button click event. Am storing logged in user id in a variable and passing in the custom variable method as the value.

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#buybutton').on('click', function() {

```
         _gaq.push( ['_setCustomVar', 2, 'gaid', <?php echo(json_encode($userName));?>, 1 ] ); 
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','button-webtrader','Click','webtrader-buttonclickevent']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution for this. Instead of custom variables, i have used event tracking to achieve this. I have used the following function in the click event of the button.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','button-category','Click','Clicked by the user:<?php echo(json_encode($userName));?> ']);
```

"$userName" above contains the logged in user id from my site. Now, i can see the clicks of a particular user using his id under Behavior->Events->Pages->Your Page->Event Category->Event Action->Event Label. As username is personally identifiable info according to google, i didn't use username.